# Mongoengine delete file gridfs

Tags: django, mongoengine, gridfs

I am using mongoengine to insert images in mongodb's GridFS.
Insert everything is ok, but I now want to delete, and I'm not getting.
I am using version 0.8.2 and I'm mongoengine to do so:

```
class Animal(Document):

         genus = StringField()
         family = StringField()
         photo = FileField()

marmot = Animal(genus='Marmota')

marmot.photo.delete()
```

Only he did not delete anything or gives error.
What am I doing wrong? Someone can help me?

Comment: Tried it, got the same result. None.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to delete, thus:

```
marmot = Animal.objects.get(id='51c80fb28774a715dc0481ae')
marmot.photo.delete()

The issue is that I'm doing my upload to GridFS with the following code:

    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        my_painting = Movie.objects.get(id=id)
                
        files = []
        for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
           mf = mongoengine.fields.GridFSProxy()
           mf.put(f, filename=f.name, legend='Oi')

           files.append(mf)
           print files
           my_painting.MovieCover = files
        my_painting.save()
```

Inserts okay.

But when I delete, using the same above gives me the following error:
'BaseList' object has no attribute 'delete'

Someone can help me?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem using one is to scroll through the images and delete one by one.

I wonder was how it was possible to delete single image by its id? Someone can help me?